# AlarmManager autostart

Tags: android

I've these class, at start set an alarm and after 10 seconds, alarm starts. There is also a reading from sharedpreferences to check if user has enable or disable the alarm.
Now, I need stars alarm also when app is not active (like after reboot) or when app is killed.
AlarmReceiver:
MainActiAlarmRAlarmReceiver:eceiver:vity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AlarmReceiver:AlarmReceiver:
    Boolean set;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        // read from sharepreferences
//      [...]
        //

        if (set){

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public final class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: This answer will you need it... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8801990/1339473

Comment: I don't understand the question clearly. In general, the alarmManager would be triggered even if the activity which starts it is not running, however, all alarmManager would fail after reboot, and you have to start the alarmManager after reboot.  So you are asking how to re-start it after reboot?

Comment: I need create an autostart class to runs the settings of alarmmanager. thanks